# C# void type- safety

Tags: c#

I am just new for C# programming (coming from C++)

My question is:
In C# every type inherits from Object
Why 'void' doesn`t?Can it cause some RT/type safety  problems or it is just semantics/syntax?

(I know that int/char etc a 'base type' and boxing/unboxing is used - my question is specific for void)

Thank you

Comment: Here are some additional musings on why "void" is odd.  http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/29/the-void-is-invariant.aspx

Answer (score 11):

In C#, [`void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) is a keyword that is used in two contexts:

- In the context of method signatures, `void` indicates the absence of a return type; it doesn't refer to a type "void" which could inherit from `object`.

  (In reflection, a return type has always to be specified. For this reason, there is a `System.Void` type in the framework, but `void` and `System.Void` cannot be used interchangeably.)
- In unsafe context, `void*` is a [pointer type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) to an unknown type. As mentioned in [the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) linked by *@Colin Mackay*, pointer types do not inherit from `object`, although they can be converted to one.

Comment: Actually System.Void is a struct in the System namespace; in mscorlib.

Comment: Right. `System.Void` is used with reflection for the same purpose. But you can't write `System.Void` in place of `void` if your method doesn't have a return type.

Comment: Good point @dtb.

I don't think void* has meaning in .NET. Essentially System.object fulfills that function.

Comment: No, void* is perfectly meaningful and does not mean "object". void* means "an unsafe pointer to unmanaged data of unknown size".  "object" means "a reference to any managed object".

Comment: Interrestingly, You CAN use void and System::Void interchangeably in Managed C++ `System::Void voidfunc(System::Void*){/*...*/}` is a valid function declaration and means the same as `void voidfunc(void*){/*...*/}`

Answer (score 8):

Not everything inherits from Object - That is a common myth. Interfaces don't inherit from Object.

See this for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx

Comment: This is true, but it's not exactly the answer to the original question.

Comment: Senfo: since the original question assumes a falsehood, it's pretty hard to answer the original question without pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C++, C# allows the void keyword only to specify that a method does not have a return type.

In C#, the void keyword is invalid as a method parameter. In C++, however, void can be used to specify a "universal" pointer.

One [caveat to this rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.80%29.aspx) is when using [unsafe code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b%28VS.80%29.aspx), which is generally unnecessary in C#.

**EDIT:** Contrary to what some others have posted, there's a difference between void and System.Void. There is a void keyword, in addition to the struct System.Void. The keyword is used to indicate that a method does not have a return type. System.Void, on the other hand, is used in reflection to ask which type a method returns (there may be other uses for System.Void, but I'm not aware of any).

[C# void keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28VS.71%29.aspx)
[C++ void keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxky5d0w%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Not 100% correct in C# void is also used in an unsafe context to declare a pointer to an unknown type.  Don't take my word, read Microsoft documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: A valid argument. I've added a caveat to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Void is not a type of object. It's a type of nothing. At least in C#, just about the only time you use the word void is as a function return type, so it means the function returns nothing. Non-existence of something can't derive from anything. The only other place to use it is in unsafe context, referring to pointers, which also do not derive from Object.

Answer (score 0):

Void is a Type, but methods that return void, don't push anything onto the stack. System.Void is declared as a struct, so it should inherit from object, too, but it's handled differently. You can see it clearer if you look at the IL code, after a method returning void is called, there is no `pop` instruction, which normally is used to pop unused return values off the stack.

EDIT: Actually, i checked. If i declare a method as returning System.Void, i get an error message stating that System.Void can't be used from C# code. But try the following:

```
typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(void))
typeof(System.ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(void))
```

that will return true, so void does derive from object and System.ValueType (i.e. struct)