# Why an operation can’t be performed as part of an assignment

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, programming-languages, syntax

I recently wrote the following statement by accident.

```
MyCollection myCollection = new MyCollection();
SomeMethod(myCollection.SomeVoidOperation());
```

Stupidly it took me some time to work out why it didn't work (Had a brainfart) but then it got me thinking; why is such a statement actually invalid in any general C type syntax context?

I understand that I can accomplish the same functionality with method chaining but what I don't get is why such a feature isn't (or perhaps can't) be implemented? To me the intent seems clear and I've tried but I can't see any ambiguity it might create. I'm sure there are some good reasons (or something that I'm missing) and hopefully someone can point it out to me.

> So, why can’t an operation be
>   performed as part of an assignment?

**UPDATE:** 
I understand why this doesn't work. IE: I have a method that expects some parameter and I am calling a method that doesn't return anything - but you are missing my point.... I see that code as two statements one is myCollection (IE: An instance) and the second is "invoke this method".

Here is a more complete example:

```
public class Stock 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class StockList : List<Stock>
{
    public void SomeSortOperation() { }
}

public void SomeMethod(StockList stockList)
{

}

StockList myList = new StockList();
SomeMethod(myList.SomeSortOperation());
```

Comment: Which kind of data returns `myCollection.SomeVoidOperation()`? And which kind of data accept `SomeMethod` as input param?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here, but `myCollection.SomeVoidOperation()` should produce a result which `SomeMethod` can accept. Or is it that you're trying to pass a void value?

Comment: I think because the compiler doesn't expect an argument. The statement will produce a result `void` which can be seen as an argument. This is just some reasoning, I don't have any reference for this.

Comment: Your question title seems entirely inappropriate - this has to do with void expressions, not assignment.

Comment: You're welcome to change it. Its the best way I could think of expressing what I was trying to achieve. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *looks* like you're trying to use the result of `SomeVoidOperation` as a method argument (presumably to a method with no arguments) - but presumably you're not, because it's a void method.

It's never a good idea for code to *look* like it's doing one thing, when it's actually doing another.

EDIT: Okay, no, having seen the edit, I *still* don't think this is a good idea. You're basically saying that if you try to use a void expression as a method argument, it should actually use some different value, based on the expression. That expression would have to be very carefully defined... for example, would:

```
Foo(x.MethodReturningBar().MethodReturningVoid());
```

consider the argument to be the type of `x`, or `Bar` (the return type of the intermediate method call)?

Again, you're writing code which *looks* like it's doing one thing (using the value of the whole expression as an argument) when it's *actually* doing something else (using the value of part of the expression as an argument). That's simply a bad idea.

Comment: Any chance you could read my update and comment? I know my thinking might be completely skewed here but I still don't see a compelling argument why allowing syntax like this would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Maxim: If your method *does* expect a parameter, but you're not giving one, why would you expect it to work? Were you expecting the result to implicitly be `myCollection`? What's the parameter type of `SomeMethod`? A more complete example would help in terms of clarity.

Comment: I guess thats exactly what I'm saying, yes the return type for that should implicitly be myCollection... Please see updated example... (Like I said I could be completely smoking crack here but I just seems natural to me)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by **SomeVoidOperation()** that the operation returns no value (void):

You can't pass nothing to a method that expects to get something. You can't cast a nothing to the type that **SomeMethod()** expects to get.

Comment: But what if the method expects nothing? Let's say void?

Comment: @RBaarda, then I would say the last sentence of Jon Skeet's answer would apply even more.

Comment: @Christian.K I do agree with Jon Skeet. But I'm just wondering how the compiler deals with such situations.

Comment: @RBaarda, it considers it invalid.

Comment: @RBaarda, sorry, don't want to nag you here, but the reason might be just what John Skeet said: because the code doesn't show the intend. The syntax implies (by common sense - and maybe that is the sole reason in first place) that you are passing an argument into a function call. Which is not what is happening, when the called function doesn't even accept a parameter (and/or the other function does not have a return value).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should backtrack a little and try to understand the `void` type first. See this answer [C# void type- safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415179/c-void-type-safety). I believe this will give more insight in why what you're trying to do doesn't work.